# How can I call a COM component using JavaScript in Mozilla?

Tags: javascript, silverlight, firefox

I am calling a COM component in IE. Here is the code

```
<object align="left" classid="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" 
        id="Winvideo-Silverlight2RTW-Hypervideo-Part1-WMVa.wmv">

    <param name="FileName" value="Winvideo-Silverlight2RTW-Hypervideo-Part1-WMVa.wmv">
    <param name="AutoRewind" value="true">
    <param name="AutoStart" value="false">    
    <param name="ClickToPlay" value="true">
    <param name="Mute" value="false">
    <param name="ShowControls" value="true">
    <param name="ShowDisplay" value="true">
    <param name="ShowTracker" value="true">
    <param name="PlayCount" value="1">

</object>
```

It is working fine in IE, but not in Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add [<object type="application/x-ms-wmp">](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb614509(VS.85).aspx).

But still, many Firefoxen and other browsers won't have Windows Media Player plugins installed. Even on IE I find it — along with QuickTime and Real — pretty unreliable... which is why most people have ended up using Flash Video these days instead of trying to embed a media player.